# Group documents by month in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Right now I have a Mongoose query which looks something like

```
Collection
  .find( selector )
  .sort( sortCriteria )
  .select( selectCriteria )
  .populate( populateCriteria1 )
  .populate( populateCriteria2 )
  .then( docs => ... )
  .catch( errHandler )
```

So I am doing quite a lot in my query.

Each document in my collection has a date. I want the documents returned grouped by month and year. So it should become something like

```
docs = [
  { _id: { year: 2017, month: 4 }, docs: [ ... ] },
  { _id: { year: 2017, month: 5 }, docs: [ ... ] },
  { _id: { year: 2017, month: 6 }, docs: [ ... ] }
]
```

I guess this is a simple `.aggregate()`, but I am not sure where I should include it since I am doing filtering using `.find()`, sorting using `.sort()`, field selection using `.select()`, and populates using `.populate()`.

Each document has the field `date`, so it might be something like

```
Collection
  .find( selector )
  .aggregate([
    { $project: { month: { $month: $date }, year: { $year },
    { $group: { _id: { $month: $date, $year: $date }, docs: { $push: '' } }
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to '$project', since you can also use the month method in `$group`

So you would get something like:

```
$group:{
    _id : { year: { $year: "$date" }, month: { $month: "$date" } },
    docs: { $push: { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field1" } }
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks but can I do it together with `populate()`? You write `$push: { field1: ...`. Is it possible to just say that it should push all the fields I have selected?